# How to identify the base weapon?

Tags: fire-emblem-fates

I just upgraded my Smithy so I want to forge some better weapons. However, I named some of my forged weapons so I don't know what base weapons I need to use to improve them. How do I identify what base weapons match my named weapons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind the slight inconvenience, the easiest way to see the original name of an item is to **erase the custom name**. Simply go to the Smithy, select the Erase Name option, and erase the item's name to reset it to the default name. Once you see what it is, you can use the Carve Name option in the Smithy to put the custom name back on it, or change it to something more recognizable. Unlike Forging, changing a forged weapon's name is free of charge.

Answer (score 0):

Equip it to a character who can use it, press the little "+" sign in the top corner, and see if it matches up to the designs of normal weapons. For instance, a Blessed Bow or Raider Yumi would look very different than a Killer Bow or an Iron Yumi. Good luck. And in the future, try naming all of one kind of weapon the same thing, so it would look like: Strong (Iron) Yumi, Strong Yumi +1, Strong Yumi +2, and so on.